# How do I instantiate a module in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've heard before that "modules are just classes too". I have a few situations, mostly unit testing and interactive interpreter experimentation, where I would like to create a module in a variable without having to create any external files. I imagine something like:

```
>>> import sys
>>>
>>> m = sys.Module() # <- This is the class I want
>>> m.foo = 'bar'
>>> m
<module 'm' (instantiated)>
>>>
>>> sys.modules['testmodule'] = m
>>>
>>> import testmodule
>>> print testmodule.foo
bar
```

Note: I am aware that I can plug any object into the modules dict, but I'm specifically interested in creating a module instance

Comment: Where did you hear that modules are classes too? There is a ModuleType, but that's not a python ClassType or similar.

Comment: Maybe you mean `objects too`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
>>> import types
>>> help(types.ModuleType)
>>> mymod = types.ModuleType("MyMod")
>>> mymod
<module 'MyMod' (built-in)>
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, just for the completeness of the answers, I noticed that types work just like classes (are they classes?) which means I could do this:

```
>>> import sys
>>> Module = type(sys)
>>>
>>> mymodule = Module('mymodule')
>>> mymodule
<module 'mymodule' (built-in)>
```

Probably not recommended to use in real world applications, but could be a timesaver in the interactive interpreter none the less

Comment: to answer your question, types and "new-style" classes are equivalent. New-style classes are those that derive from the built-in `object` class. Old-style classes (those that don't derive from `object) are not types. In python3, all classes are types.